# How to set permanent variable for non-terminal session (bash)?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, ubuntu-16.04

I want to use my own specific variable KILL, but I can't find a way to make it visible for non-terminal session

By now I tried to add KILL=0 and export KILL=0 to ~/.profile, but that doesn't seem to work (when I tried to echo KILL into some txt file, it showed empty lines only, example - echo $KILL >> test.txt)

What should I do to make my variable visible for non-terminal sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux using "bash" you will need to put the variable into `~/.bash_profile`. Then it will be available when you open a new terminal where you would launch `echo $KILL`. After you re-login, it should be available to any process you launch even outside terminal as long as it's going to try to use it.

The variable can be also put in `/etc/profile` (to be set for all users) or `/etc/environment` (to be set for all users and processes started by the system).

Comment: It finally worked, after placing variable to /etc/environment
thanks